# MVC updating .edmx files (.msl, .csdl, .ssdl)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have 3 .edmx files (.msl, .csdl, .ssdl) in my root project directory where the web.config is.  Why are these not updating when I do a 'update model from database'?

I have to manually add the new fields to these files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.msl, .csdl and .ssdl are result of .edmx compilation, if you do not embedd them into assembly check that "EntityDeploy" is selected for "Build Action" in .edmx file properties (in Solution Explorer) and "Copy to Output Directory" is selected for "Metadata Artifact Processing" in model properties (in model designer), update your model and rebuild solution. After that they will be copied to bin\Debug subfolder.

BTW, you could select "Embedd into Output Assembly", update connection string, remove references to these files from solution and do not care about them anymore.