# Entity Framework .edmx update does not update .msl, .csdl, .ssdl files

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, edmx

I am working on an ASP.net project, targeting **.Net Framework v4.6** and **Visual Studio 2015 Update 3**. This project uses **Entity Framework v5**. I recently tried to add new entities using the Visual Studio Model designer (by double clicking .edmx file).

Steps that I followed:

1. Open .edmx from Solution Explorer
2. Right Click -> Update Model from Database
3. Chose the specific column under the Refresh tab
4. Save the .edmx file
5. Build Solution

I noticed that only the .edmx file and any associated .cs files (model) were updated. The `.csdl`, `.msl` and `.ssdl` files were not updated with these new values, causing Runtime Exceptions within the web application.

**Exact RuntimeException**:

> System.Data.MappingException: The number of members in the conceptual
>   type 'XYZ' does not match with the number of members on the object
>   side type 'XYZ'. Make sure the number of members are the same.

What could be the root cause for the associated files (`.csdl`, `.msl` and `.ssdl`) to be stale ?

NOTE: I tried all possible solution available online, but none of the them seems to solve this issue ('Run Custom Tool', Change visual layout within the edmx file, etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC updating .edmx files (.msl, .csdl, .ssdl)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561534/mvc-updating-edmx-files-msl-csdl-ssdl)

Comment: @PranavPatel: I tried the steps listed in the suggested post, but it still results in the same Runtime Exception.

Comment: @RohitV Did you got any solution for this issue ?

Comment: @Mayank Yes. So, we had moved to a new version Visual Studio which broke the build. Solution was to include a Pre-Build Step that triggers `EdmGen.exe`. This tool re-generates the `.csdl`, `.msl` and `.ssdl` files.