# Database-first project: missing CSDL file prevents project being built

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-database-first

Current project:

- DotNet 4.7.1
- MVC 5
- Database-first from a legacy DB, `[DbName].edmx` file in `/Models/`

When trying to build the project in order to test it, I am getting a sudden error (CS1566) that there was an error reading the resource `Models.[DbName].csdl`, and it could not find part of the path. Sure enough, the entire `\edmxResourcesToEmbed\Models\` folder was missing from the `\obj\Debug\` directory.

How do I rebuild this? This is my first database-first project, everything else has been code-first, and Google is bringing me back nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to StackOverflow’s ability to link in other posts you would normally not think were related, I was able to solve this problem.

This issue also came about because of code-first workflows that I had adopted that I needed in order to prevent errors under code first using multi-project repository patterns. Specifically, I modified my `*.csproj` files to always delete the `bin` and `obj` directories of the project(s) that I build/publish:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <!-- Remove obj folder -->
  <RemoveDir Directories="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)" />
  <!-- Remove bin folder -->
  <RemoveDir Directories="$(BaseOutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

Why? Because when I didn’t, any attempt to build/publish a code-first project would fail due to “multiple, conflicting web.config files”. Which I don’t have in the first place, but that’s what it complains about. So by habit, I just engineer each project to delete those two directories before building/publishing, so as to avoid that show-stopping error.

Essentially: the system was giving itself a fatal haircut every time it went to build or publish, by clearing out a `bin` file that was needed by the publish process. All thanks to me and code-first multi-project repository pattern solutions applied to a database-first project. Sweet. *facepalm bridgepinch smh*

And when I first made this post, I [got one Related link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15571502/932002) shortly *after* posting. The first half of that reply made sense - select the `*.edmx` file and change the `Build Action` value, but the second half confused me until I actually opened up the `*.edmx` file and clicked on an empty part of the model diagram that came up -- suddenly, my properties sidebar changed to something completely different, which *did* have the `Metadata Artifact Processing` value that needed changing.

By following those instructions, then shutting down VS, then removing my `*.csproj` modifications, then opening the project back up, then building, then reversing those instructions and actually publishing, I was able to reverse the damage I had inadvertently done.

So, FYI for anyone else who has the same problem.